# Query NOT IN a null subquery returning null instead of the whole table

Tags: mysql

My work is for an appointment system:
I have two tables:

```
Times(hour varchar);
Reservations(time varchar, date varchar);
```

Times table have all the times a store is open (as strings) from 8 to 6pm (08:00,08:30,09:00,etc..)
Reservation has the times reserved. 
The store has 3 employees that can do an appointment simultaneously, so 3 client can reserve at 10:00am per example.

My goal is to return the list of times that aren't reserved but on one condition: If a time has been reserved less than 3 times it can still be reserved. I tried this query

```
SELECT `hour` FROM `times` WHERE `hour` NOT IN (SELECT `time` FROM `reservations` WHERE `date` = '$date' HAVING COUNT(`time`)>=3);
```

The problem is this returns null if there are no reserved times, but i cant understand why.. If the subquery returns null, the first query not in subquery(null) must return all the times in the Times table right? Its giving me empty rows... Anyone know why?

Comment: The subquery is missing a GROUP BY

Comment: ``WHERE `date` = '$date'`` should be ``WHERE `date` = ?``, always parameterize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT `time` 
FROM `reservations` 
WHERE `date` = '$date' 
GROUP BY `time`
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

returns *the list of times that are reserved* under your condition.
So use a LEFT JOIN of `Times` to that query and return only the unmatched rows:

```
SELECT t.`hour` 
FROM `times` t LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `time` 
    FROM `reservations` 
    WHERE `date` = '$date' 
    GROUP BY `time`
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) r on r.time = t.`hour`
WHERE r.time IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for this, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If subquery returns null, then IN operator will always give you null as result. If you want to get results ensure you don't have nulls in subquery or make subquery return empty set. I tried it on SQL server.